# Word press Not Displaying Theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or mis configuration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: enable the error its fatal error

Comment: Have you got any error message ?

Comment: Please enable errors  `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` in `wp-config.php`

Comment: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 41943040 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1280 bytes) in /hermes/bosnacweb05/bosnacweb05am/b2049/dom.vellian315692215/wb_felskinn.com/wp-admin/includes/misc.php on line 743

Comment: i will change wp-config.php file ini_set('display_erros',1);

Comment: i will change file wp-admin.php define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );

Comment: it will be working thanks ramesh S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increase memory limit in 3 ways,

**Edit your wp-config.php file**

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M'); // if this is not in your wp-config file.
```

**Edit your PHP.ini file**

If you have access to your PHP.ini file, change the line in PHP.ini

```
memory_limit = 256M ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (64MB) //If your line shows 64M try 256M:
```

**Edit your .htaccess file**

If you don’t have access to PHP.ini try adding this to an .htaccess file:

```
 php_value memory_limit 256M
```

Hope this will help you.